# Break line in For Next loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

I have 2 nested loop as shown below.

Corresponding variables x and y are the x-axis, y-axis. When x runs from 1 to 10 and then back down a similar line

for example:

`x = (1 -> 10) then y = 1`

`x = (11 -> 20) then y = 2`

`x = (xn -> XNN) then y = n`

It's like this

```
Private Sub R1(ByRef RoomTotal As Integer, ByRef RoomInLine As Integer, ByRef RoomW As Integer, RoomH As Integer, ByRef RoomPrefix As String, ByRef RoomTopLeft As Integer, RoomMargin As Integer)

    Dim TotalRoomLine As Integer
    If RoomTotal Mod RoomInLine <> 0 Then
        TotalRoomLine = RoomTotal \ RoomInLine + 1
    Else
        TotalRoomLine = RoomTotal / RoomInLine
    End If

    For y As Integer = 1 To TotalRoomLine Step 1

            For x As Integer = 1 To RoomTotal Step 1

            Dim RoomNo As New Button
            If x <= RoomInLine Then
                RoomNo.Top = RoomTopLeft
                RoomNo.Left = RoomTopLeft + (RoomW * (x - 1)) + (RoomMargin * (x - 1))
                RoomNo.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlLightLight
            ElseIf RoomInLine < x <= (RoomInLine * y) Then
                RoomNo.Top = RoomTopLeft + (RoomH * (y - 1)) + (RoomMargin * (y - 1))
                RoomNo.Left = RoomTopLeft + (RoomW * (x - 1)) + (RoomMargin * (x - 1))
                RoomNo.ForeColor = Color.Green
            End If

                RoomNo.Width = RoomW
                RoomNo.Height = RoomH
                RoomNo.Name = RoomPrefix & Convert.ToString(x)
                RoomNo.Text = RoomPrefix & Convert.ToString(x)
                RoomNo.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark

                RoomNo.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
                RoomNo.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
                Me.Controls.Add(RoomNo)
            Next
        Next

End Sub


i call function: R1(36, 10, 100, 100, "ROOM", 100, 5)
```

Only the first line is displayed properly used 2 it started showing incorrect

This is the result when running code on http://imageshack.com/a/img34/9489/drue.png

I want it to run like this new precise

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYTFW.png

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: current it show : http://imageshack.com/a/img34/9489/drue.png only line 1 form x = 1 to 10 is correct. x = 11 to totalroom not. Thankyou Szymon.

Comment: You mean it goes to 12 instead of 11 in the second line?

Comment: each line is only 10 buttons created. that i have x = n then y = n/10 = (line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many loops. Try this:

```
For iRoom As Integer = 0 To RoomTotal - 1

    Dim RoomNo As New Button
    Dim x As Integer = iRoom Mod RoomInLine
    Dim y As Integer = iRoom \ RoomInLine
    RoomNo.Top = RoomTop + (RoomH + RoomMargin) * y
    RoomNo.Left = RoomLeft + (RoomW + RoomMargin) * x

    RoomNo.Width = RoomW
    RoomNo.Height = RoomH
    RoomNo.Name = RoomPrefix & Convert.ToString(iRoom + 1)
    RoomNo.Text = RoomPrefix & Convert.ToString(iRoom + 1)
    RoomNo.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark

    RoomNo.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
    RoomNo.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    Me.Controls.Add(RoomNo)

Next
```